# How to minimize CPU consumption with a fixed thread loop period

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

I use pthread lib 2.8 and the OS kernel is Linux 2.6.37 on arm. In my program, Thread A is using pthread interfaces to set scheduling priority to the halfway point between `sched_get_priority_min(policy)` and `sched_get_priority_max(policy)`.

In the thread function loop:

```
{
    //do my work
    pthread_cond_timedwait(..., ... , 15 ms)
}
```

I find this thread consumes about 3% CPU. If I change the timeout to 30 ms, it reduces to 1.3%. However, I can not increase the timeout. Is there a way to reduce the CPU consumption without reducing the timeout? It seems the cost is due to thread switching.

Comment: What does "do my work" actually involve? Or, put another way, why do you think the "cost of thread switch" is the major component. What processor are you running this on? I did an experiment using similar things to your code, and it comes out with 0.0% CPU usage.

Comment: I use ARM cortex risc ARMv7 @800Mhz。 I cancel all the work and do test: wait 15ms 0.88%~1.75%; wait 30 ms 0%. The program is debug edition which is -o0 level @Mats Petersson

Comment: @MatsPetersson Now my thread loop is just : pthread_cond_timedwait(time)

Comment: Ok, so that's a little slower than my AMD quad core processor, and may explain why it's taking up that much time. I'm not sure there is much you can do about that. You are, after all waking up every 15ms (so 60 times in a second), which will take SOME amount of time, and the OS will schedule something else in the meantime (even if it's just the "idle" thread).

Comment: @MatsPetersson Thank you.I will read book about multi-thread and Posix thread ,then try to understand the COST.

Comment: What CPU usage do you get if you simply put a "sleep(15);" in there, instead of using a condition variable?

Comment: @MatsPetersson almost the same, very little difference, seems usleep(1000*15) have lower CPU usage.

Comment: I upped my rate to 1ms and there is a little bit of difference between the `usleep(15000);` and `cv.wait_for(lk, std::chrono::milliseconds(1));` (I'm using C++11 code to do conditional wait, so cv is a condition variable, lk is a mutex wrapped with unique lock).

Answer (score 0):

Using this sort of construct will cause approximately 67 task switches per second, and most likely that switches to a different process, which means a complete context switch including page-tables. It's been a while since I looked at what that involves in ARM, but I'm sure it's not a "Lightweight" operation. If we count backwards, 1.75% of that is about 210k clock cycles per task switch. Which seems quite a lot. But I'm not sure how much work is involved in scrubbing TLB's, caches and such.